# Impact from upgrading SQL Server 2005 SP3 Native Client have Connected Clients?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, upgrade, sql-server-native-client

I'm in the process of upgrading some of my SQL Server 2005 SP3 (build 9.00.4060.0) instances to SQL Server 2005 SP4 RTM (build 9.00.5000.0) before I go ahead and upgrade instances on the same server which are currently used by the business. Once I see the installation is successful, I will proceed with install SP4 on the rest of the instances and then move forward with our production server.

**Question**

If I upgrade the Native Client on the server, do I have to upgrade the Native Client on all of my office employees desktops also? or can they simply stay on the current version of their Native Client and I can go ahead with just the server/instances upgrade?

Thanks,

Michael Murray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any changes to the SQL client in SP4. I wouldn't bother unless after upgrade, someone has problems connecting.

Comment: Thanks Robert, appreciate the help.